# About punctuation: why did the author use double apostrophe in can't?

Tags: punctuation

**EDUCATION CAN"T WAIT**

I have come across the aforementioned title somewhere on a newspaper. Why did the author use double apostrophe  (") in can't...

Comment: Can you provide a citation for this title?  For example, the name and date of the newspaper, and the page that the article appeared on?  Or a link to an on-line copy of the article?

Comment: The citation will help us guess whether the error was accidental, or on purpose.  (With this title, a punctuation error could be a humorous example of the alleged need for education.)

Comment: I'm reluctant to close this until we know whether it is accidental or deliberate.  A deliberate typo has additional meaning which may not be obvious to a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "double apostrophe". What you saw was a printer's error, or as Jasper suggests, an attempt at humour.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if someone were typing that sentence on a US qwerty keyboard while holding the shift key, then an apostrophe could easily be replaced with a quotation mark by mistake. I don't think this is the case in all keyboard layouts, so this possibility may not be obvious to many on this site.